# What happens when the kafka log is rolled over? Does a consumer miss the messages in the old log file?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I've just added a messages that caused a log rollover in Kafka. Therefore this message and the one immediately before it are now in the archived/rolled log file. Do I miss these messages, in other words, if now a consumer comes along it will not be receiving this messages? How does Kafka handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will still be able to retrieve messages in log segments that have been rolled and from a consumer perspective you will not notice any difference. Messages are available for consumption until the retention criteria has been reached and old log segments are deleted.